# while running yfinance i get the following error

Tags: yfinance

```
import yfinance as yf
ticker = "AAPL"

stockdata = yf.download(ticker, start="2021-1-1", end="2021-1-10")

-----------------------------------------
Exception in thread Thread-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\multitasking\__init__.py", line 102, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 169, in _download_one_threaded
    data = _download_one(ticker, start, end, auto_adjust, back_adjust,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 181, in _download_one
    return Ticker(ticker).history(period=period, interval=interval,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 157, in history
    data = data.json()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling/upgrading `yfinance` and make sure you are connected to internet

then execute

```
import yfinance as yf
stockdata = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-01-01", end="2021-01-10")
print(stockdata)
```

after executing I got

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close     Volume
Date
2020-12-31  134.080002  134.740005  131.720001  132.690002  132.267349   99116600
2021-01-04  133.520004  133.610001  126.760002  129.410004  128.997803  143301900
2021-01-05  128.889999  131.740005  128.429993  131.009995  130.592697   97664900
2021-01-06  127.720001  131.050003  126.379997  126.599998  126.196747  155088000
2021-01-07  128.360001  131.630005  127.860001  130.919998  130.502991  109578200
2021-01-08  132.429993  132.630005  130.229996  132.050003  131.629379  105158200
```

If your problem exists, please let me know which IDE you are using to execute the code